# ImportError in airflow: No module named acme.operators.dwh_operators

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to follow the tutorial found here: https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/etlexample.html and I got as far as the "Drop dags into airflow" step.  At this point I got the following error on my Airflow dashboard:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/my_name/airflow/dags/product_staging.py] No module named acme.operators.dwh_operators
```

This is what my path for the module looks like: `airflow_home/dags/acme/operators/dwh_operators.py`

What do I need to do to get airflow to pick it up?

Thanks.

Comment: As per my understanding, Airflow does not support 2 level down in dags folder but supports only 1 down. If you will try to put dwh_operators.py in acme/ and import like from acme import dwh_operators then it should work.